# CardView is not wrapping multiline EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, androidx

I am trying to wrap the text in EditText but its not working. I have tried many solutions from stackoverflow but nothing is working for me.

Here is the EditText code within card view layout.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:tint="#00897B"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sentiment_satisfied" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_chat_log"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Write a message..."
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:tint="#00897B"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Here is the complete xml file code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#E8E9E4"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#075E54"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lyt_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_medium">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat_back_press"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_medium"
            android:layout_height="0dp" />

        <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:src="@drawable/photo_male_8"
            app:civ_border="true"
            app:civ_border_color="#075E54"
            app:civ_border_width="0dp"
            app:civ_shadow="true"
            app:civ_shadow_radius="0" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Roberts"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            app:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Online"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_10" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/chat_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <!--        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView-->
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_chat_log"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing_medium"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:scrollingCache="true"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_soft"
        android:rotation="180" />

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

    <!--        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView-->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
        app:cardElevation="1dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spacing_small"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/spacing_small">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:tint="#00897B"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_sentiment_satisfied" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_chat_log"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Write a message..."
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:scrollbars="none" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_xmlarge"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:tint="#00897B"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_photo_camera" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <!--        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton-->
    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/send_button_chat_log"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#00897B"
        app:elevation="1dp"
        app:fabSize="mini"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mic"
        app:useCompatPadding="false" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your layout design with several problems. The critical one is that parent limited the view. Height of EditText is set as match_parent. It will match your linear layout. The fast way to resolve your problem just modify following statements.

1. The content layout should be wrap too.

   ```
       <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_small"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
           app:cardCornerRadius="18dp"
           app:cardElevation="1dp">

           <LinearLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--here-->
   ```
2. Your EditText should be wrap too.

   ```
               <EditText
               android:id="@+id/edittext_chat_log"
               android:layout_width="0dp"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content" <!--here-->
               android:layout_weight="1"
   ```
3. If you don't want to limit the height, please remove android:lines="5"
4. If you want to limit the lines to 10, just keep android:lines="10", not need to keep android:maxLines="10" and android:minLines="1"

Then problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In your `EditText`, try setting singleLine=false. Since a value is specified for inputType. 
Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:singleLine
*android:singleLine
Constrains the text to a single horizontally scrolling line instead of letting it wrap onto multiple lines, and advances focus instead of inserting a newline when you press the enter key. The default value is false (multi-line wrapped text mode) for non-editable text, but if you specify any value for inputType, the default is true (single-line input field mode).
May be a boolean value, such as "true" or "false".*

````
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittext_chat_log"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:hint="Write a message..."
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"

                android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                android:lines="5"
                android:maxLines="10"
                android:minLines="1"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_middle"
                android:scrollbars="none" />```
````

Comment: Just tried android:singleLine = "false" and android:scrollHorizontally="false", but its still not working. Appreciate your time :)